# Keras tuner error: logits and labels must have the same first dimension

Tags: python, keras-tuner

I'm working on my own dataset and trying to fine-tune the parameters using the Keras tuner.I'm using the basic model-building function:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras_tuner import RandomSearch

def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(
        layers.Dense(
            units=hp.Int("units", min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32),
            activation="relu",
        )
    )
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            hp.Choice("learning_rate", values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
        ),
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    return model
```

After showing the search space summary and trying to search the best values from the following code statement:

```py
tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=15, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

the following error was raised:

> logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape
> [32,10] and labels shape [6144]

I tried to change the loss to `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` and `'categorical_crossentropy'` but it didn't work.

My dataset shape is as follows:

```py
x_test (201, 16)
y_test (201, 16, 12)
X_train (1803, 16)
y_train (1803, 16, 12)
x_val (500, 16)
y_val (500, 16, 12)
```

Comment: could you provide your network structure

Comment: Sure, I updated the post.

Comment: your target is 3D while your network produces 2D output